# How to create custom data table directive using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Right now I am using `ng-datatable` for displaying data in a table, but I want to write a **custom directive** to display data in a table grid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend going to another site for the tutorial on creating a directive/component. Nothing really beats the AngularJS site itself, but there is a ton out there.  For directives [AngularJS Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), for components [AngularJS Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).  Considering web components are more robust than directives I would recommend going the path of the components.

For example:
You can split your grid into many different factions for modular/reusable components throughout your project.  Create a component for your header, a single row (pass each record from your collection into the row component), a pagination component, filter/search component, etc.

Good luck on your endeavors.

Comment: i want it to write it for whole application,like **datatable**

Comment: If you look at the documented links it should show you how to do this.  If you want to just create a data-table, you simply make your template a data-table and you'd bind the data or inject your service call to pull the data needed for the data-table.  There are about a hundred possible solutions so you have to engineer it yourself to what fits your need.  Kind of hard to give you the specific way.